# How do I use Slack blocks from Dialogflow fullfillment?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am writing a Slack bot using Dialog flow. I'd like to respond to a fulfillment request using [Slack blocks](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/payload). Unfortunately, whenever I include `blocks` in my response, my bot stops working.

Here's what I've have now:

```
return {
    status_code: 200,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: {
        payload: {
            slack: {
                blocks: [{
                  type: "section",
                  text: {
                    type: "mrkdwn",
                    text: "_No logs matched_  :iggy-ghastly:"
                  }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This code return an HTTP 200 with a JSON body. It works just fine when I use a `text` payload:

```
payload: {
    slack: {
        text: "this shows up"
    }
}
```

Does Dialogflow support Slack blocks? Are there any example of this online? How could I better debug my interactions with Dialogflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block kit payload will need to be for Dialogflow's response payload's attachments.

```
{
  "slack": {
    "attachments": [
      {
        "blocks":[
          {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
              "type": "mrkdwn",
              "text": "_No logs matched_"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- If you do not need fancy UI like Block Kit and you are okay with the response in attachment format, check out what [slack attachements](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments) can do.
  *You can test it out by add response [custom payload](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages) in dialogflow*
- If you want to use Block Kit and not in attachment format. You can response fulfillment request with an empty response. Then use [slack API chat.postMessage methods](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) to post a message directly from server to slack in block kit format.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

let postOptions = {
    uri: 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${YOUR_BOT_TOKEN}`,
    },
    json: {
        //Watch out dialogflow has different fulfillment request body 
        depends on if the user typed or clicked buttons

        "channel": req.OriginalRequest.data.event.channel,
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "text": {
                    "type": "mrkdwn",
                    "text": "_No logs matched_"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
rp(postOptions, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

I hope the above information is helpful and answer your questions.

Comment: Thank you! I got more time to work on this project and this is now working as expected :D